# How to avoid printing junk when printing numbers in columns?

Tags: c++, printf

This code takes all the numbers from a file and separates them into three columns depending on conditions. Each number can appear in one or multiple columns.

```
while(!feof(fp)) {
    i++;
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &b);
    if(b%2==0) {
        arr[j]=b;
        j++;
    }

    if(b%2==1) {
        arr2[jj]=b;
        jj++;
    }else if(i>b){
        printf(" ");
    }



    if(b%5==0) {
        arr3[jjj]=b;
        jjj++;
    }else if(i>b){
        printf(" ");
    }
}

while(a < j || a < jj || a < jjj){
    printf("       %3d           %3d             %3d \n", arr[a],arr2[a],arr3[a]);
    a++;
```

it outputs them like this:

```
     Even:           Odd:        Divisible by 5:
      10            3               10
      20            7               20
      22           13               30
      24           21               -234455 
      26           29               0
      30           344208           2056
```

It outputs junk (addresses) fornumbers beyond the end. I tried but I can't clean them up.

Ideas?

Comment: What is `fp`? What is `j`? What is `jjj`? What is `b`? Or `a`? What about `arr`? We don't see your declarations, so we have no idea of their types. And given your names, we also have no idea what they *mean*.

Comment: It is very likely that you are showing trash that occurs in uninitialized array indexes (those to which no value has been assigned).

Comment: You are printing like in example 6 even numbers and arr got 6 of them but arr1 and arr2 got less but you are printing 6 of them aswell so they are printing junk from memory

Comment: The question was deemed off-topic, a decision with which I disagree. I hope the question gets reopened; if not, I'll maybe write an answer in comments.

Comment: @anatolyg The question lacks a [MCVE]. It definitely should be closed until properly edited. If you have to guess parts of the code in order to answer the question that's unacceptable.

Comment: Since you labeled as C++, you should use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Arrays can overrun.  Allocating too large of an array wastes memory; allocating too small size means the data doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you're going to run into is there might be fewer numbers divisible by 5 than even or odd.

I would suggest making sure a is less than the respective max array number before printing.  Maybe print a tab or space if not.

Answer (score 0):

One way to clean up your output is to do the printing conditionally. This way, you cannot print all three numbers using one `printf` statement, and have to do it separately:

```
while(a < j || a < jj || a < jjj)
{
    if (a < j)
        printf("  %3d  ", arr[a]);
    else
        printf("  %3s  ", "");

    if (a < jj)
        printf("  %3d  ", arr2[a]);
    else
        printf("  %3s  ", "");

    if (a < jjj)
        printf("  %3d  ", arr3[a]);
    else
        printf("  %3s  ", "");

    putchar('\n');

    a++;
}
```

Here I use `%3s` and empty string to make sure the empty fields line up nicely with the numbers. You could just print a bunch of spaces instead, but then you'd have to edit your code carefully to make sure there is a correct number of spaces.

---

It's possible to stuff the logic for conditional printing into the `printf`'s format specifiers, and do all the printing with one statement, but this would make the code harder to understand and modify. Something like this:

```
bool is_valid1 = (a < j);
int int_field1 = is_valid1 ? 3 : 0;
int int_value1 = is_valid1 ? arr[j] : 0;
int str_field1 = 3 - int_field1;

bool is_valid2 = (a < jj);
int int_field2 = is_valid2 ? 3 : 0;
int int_value2 = is_valid2 ? arr2[jj] : 0;
int str_field2 = 3 - int_field2;

bool is_valid3 = (a < jjj);
int int_field3 = is_valid3 ? 3 : 0;
int int_value3 = is_valid3 ? arr3[jjj] : 0;
int str_field3 = 3 - int_field3;

printf("  %*.d%*s   %*.d%*s   %*.d%*s\n",
    int_field1, int_value1, str_field1, "",
    int_field2, int_value2, str_field2, "",
    int_field3, int_value3, str_field3, "");
```

Here the `%*.d` format specifier tells printf that the width for my integer field is a parameter to `printf`. I calculate it to be either 3 (if the integer is valid) or 0 (if it's invalid). The dot `.` tells it to print nothing if the field's width is 0.